# Declare array filled with zeroes PHP

Tags: php, arrays, declaration

Please bare with my I'm used in C++. I want to use an array in PHP (with variable size) but it must be filled with zeroes uppon declaration. I know that I shouldn't "declare" variables and arrays in PHP but I need it filled before use.

`$counter[] = {0};` Sends out an "unexpected '{' in line 53" error although this would perfectly work in C++. I had wrote that code in another server and it worked perfectly (in PHP) but it stoped working when I moved the files. What can I use for similar results?

Comment: `C++ !== PHP` - Perhaps consider using [array_fill()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) to create it?

Comment: I don't believe `{0}` has ever been valid syntax in PHP - just `0` should do the job. Or use `array_fill`, as @MarkBaker says.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_fill - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php

EG:

```
$counter = array_fill(0,5,0);
```

5 being the amount of 0's you want.

Comment: The problem with array_fill is that you need to declare an ammount of "0's" you want. I need a variable size array that by default has the value 0 in it. Of course it might be the case with PHP that every array is filled with 0's and not NULL's like C++ but I'm not sure.